# ошибка Mixed Content при получении данных на plnkr

Tags: httpclient, angular4

Проблема такая: необходимо получить данные с http://www.minsktrans.by/city/minsk/stops.txt с помощью HttpClient.
В моем случае в консоле при нажатии на кнопку должна выводится вся инфа.
Вот ошибка:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https:// plnkr.co/edit/...' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.minsktrans.by/city/minsk/stops.txt'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Ссылка на plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GjxQ1UGdodPXmG0MCuRJ?p=preview

Реализация

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
<button (click)="getPost()">Get data </button>
 `
})
export class AppComponent {

readonly ROOT_URL = 'http://www.minsktrans.by/city/minsk/stops.txt';

constructor (private http: HttpClient) {}

getPost() {

const that = this;

this.http
  .get(this.ROOT_URL, {responseType: 'text'})
  .subscribe((data) => {
   console.log(that.stops);
    }
  );

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ошибка, которую ты указываешь, происходит только если планкер открыт по https. Если же он открыт по http-ссылке из вопроса, такой ошибки нет.
2. При открытии по http происходит другая ошибка:

   > Failed to load http://www.minsktrans.by/city/minsk/stops.txt: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access.

   Собственно, в ней всё написано: из-за [CORS](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) браузер не позволяет получить ответ сервера. То, что надо сделать, тоже написано в сообщении об ошибке: надо соответствующим образом задать закголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` при отправке запрашиваемого файла.

Comment: как этот заголовок задать?

Comment: А откуда я знаю, на чём у тебя там сервер? А если не у тебя, то никак.

Comment: просто мне необходимо реализовать прокси средствами angular-cli/webpack на  http://www.minsktrans.by/city/minsk/stops.txt', как бы на компе в angular-cli приложении с помощью proxy.config файла все норм, но нужно код разместить на plunkr(

Comment: @kitik, ещё раз: если сервер, отдающий файл не твой, то никак. Если надо только у себя на компе, то можно браузер с соответствующим флагом запустить. Но тогда было бы не надо на планкере. Ещё можно поискать уже существующие прокси, которые будет добавлять нужный заголовок и запрашивать файл у них.

Comment: Получается с заданием что-то не так? https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ndj0GiFjvDg5_zmglZRV6nYjqQ3uRT4Vs7v4JezQcVM/edit